# Dropping heading from top

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating front page of my website and I want to drop the heading when the page is loaded this is what I tried

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#heading, #tag_line").hide();
  $("#heading").slideDown(1000);

});
```

```css
  #header {
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid lightgrey;
}

#header_content {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.brandmark {
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.link_to a {
  color: #0050A0 !important;
}

#featured_div {
  display: none;
}

#home_div {
  background-color: #0050A0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  color: white;
  height: 200px;
}

#home_div_content {
  text-align: center
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="home_div">
 <div class="container" id="home_div_content">
  <h1 id="heading">Find your product!</h1>
  <h4 id="tag_line">Search what you are looking for.</h4>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" />
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Instead of dropping from sky it just fades in sort of something. Can anyone help how to achieve it?

Comment: not sure. but is it something you are expecting? https://jsfiddle.net/sk9x5a94/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `animate()` to reveal the div in an animation rather than `slideDown()` which will cause it to appear to "open".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#home_div_content').animate({
    top: '0px'
  }, 1000 );
});
```

```css
#home_div {
  background-color: #0050A0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  height: 200px;
}

#home_div_content {
  text-align: center
}
#home_div_content {
  top: -300px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="home_div">
 <div class="container" id="home_div_content">
  <h1 id="heading">Find your product!</h1>
  <h4 id="tag_line">Search what you are looking for.</h4>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" />
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to animate the element position.

What you're doing is animating the element height.

You can do something like this to create your desired effect.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#home_div_content").animate({
    top: 50
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).css({
      'position': 'relative'
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#home_div_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#header {
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid lightgrey;
}

#header_content {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.brandmark {
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.link_to a {
  color: #0050A0 !important;
}

#featured_div {
  display: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #0050A0;
  color: white;
}

#home_div_content {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="home_div">
  <div class="container" id="home_div_content">
    <h1 id="heading">Find your product!</h1>
    <h4 id="tag_line">Search what you are looking for.</h4>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#heading, #tag_line").hide();
```

It will hide both the heading tags but then the following code makes in slide back up during the page load:

```
$("#heading").slideDown(1000);
```

If you don't want both the headings to be visible, take of the above line which makes the hidden heading to slide back up and make it visible.